# Selecting a random row from a table - DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE is giving same row when executed from two different users

Tags: sql, database, oracle, random

A quick help folks!
My application needs to randomly fetch a single value from a table in my Oracle database with around 200,000 rows. Multiple users might be using the application at the same time, so the purpose is to have all of them see a different value everytime they use click on a button. Once a row has been used, as mark it as used and don't use it again.
Here's the sample of the query that I am using:

```
        SELECT
           MY_COLUMN
        FROM
               ( SELECT
                        MY_COLUMN
                 FROM
                        MY_TABLE
                 WHERE
                       COLUMN_STATUS = 'Not used'
                 ORDER BY
                        DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE )
             WHERE
                 ROWNUM = 1;
```

It works when I use on a single user, it gives me a different value every single time. But I did a test in which I logged in with two different users on two different machines, and I clicked the "button" at the same moment, and on both users I got the same value. Am I missing something here? Is that how DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE is supposed to behave?
If yes, do you have any suggestion that can solve the above problem.

Thanks,
I appreciate your help people!

Comment: How many rows in your MY_TABLE table have the value 'Not used' in COLUMN_STATUS? The total number of rows (200k) is irrelevant, what IS relevant is how many rows meet the WHERE condition. If, for example, only four rows do, then the odds of "randomly" getting the same row are a little over 4%. Are you able to REPLICATE the behavior you noticed, or did it just happen once?

Comment: Around 140,000 rows are not used.

Comment: No, it was not a one-off event. I was able to re-create it.

Comment: Is this within a package, or some other PL/SQL code? Or a script? The only thing that comes to mind is that the SEED procedure (or perhaps the obsolete INITIALIZE procedure) in the DBMS_RANDOM package is called right before the snippet you shared.